# Inline Style attribute getting stripped off

Tags: css, visual-editor, html-editor

I am trying to style a particular section of a blog post using the WordPress editor in HTML mode.

```
<div style="background: red;">
Special section
</div>
```

The works fine. But when I add `background-image` property, the whole `style` attribute gets stripped off when viewed on the blog.

```
<div style="background:red; background-image:url(https://.....jpg);">
Special section
</div>
```

How can I define and load css style for a specific post without editing in functions.php or adding definitions in Customizer Additional CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in your code, background image should have "",

check this example

```
background-image: url("paper.gif");
```

[W3](https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/pr_background-image.asp)